# Kendo Mobile Widget Button Group Wrap to width -> newline

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-mobile, buttongroup

I have a very long button group made using the kendo mobile widget but it goes off the screen. It has to work on an iPad.

Is there a way to create a newline once it gets too long for the screen?

I have tried word wrap:break-word and max width but nothing seems to do it

```
<ul id="buttonGrp" data-role="buttongroup"></ul>

var a = 97;

for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
      $("<li class='km-button'>" + String.fromCharCode(a + i) + </li>").appendTo("#buttonGrp ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution

```
#buttonGrp li
{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On old android devices this solution doesn't work.
Try this.

```
#selectList {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    white-space: normal !important;
}

#selectList li {
    float: left;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: block;
    white-space: normal !important;

}
```